# Javascript Object Assign and Structural Sharing

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, immutability

I've been experimenting with concepts of immutability with javascript objects. I was wondering if the following code example implements what I believe is known as "Structural Sharing" (see: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e-5obm1G_FY&start=1123).

```
const objectFirst = {
  key1: 1,
  key2: 2
}

const updateObject = (lastObject) => {
  const updatedObject = {...lastObject, ...{ key2: 4 }}  // Object.assign({}, lastObject, { key2: 4 })
  return updatedObject
}

const objectNext = updateObject(objectFirst)
```

objectNext is now { key1: 1, Key2: 4 } and objectFirst is unchanged. But has key1 been duplicated? Or, is their now essentially a reference to key1's location in memory shared by both objects?

I'm basically just asking if this approach implements some sort of "Structural Sharing"? One could see that if this were not the case, then it would lead to significant memory bloat.

Comment: No this is not that. You can verify that by changing `objectFirst.key1` and see if it reflects in `objectNext`.

Comment: Both objects have distinct `key1` properties. There's no property sharing in any visible way, though one  never knows what goes on internally.

Comment: For structural sharing you need a tree-like data structure. The simplest tree is an unary tree, where each node has one or no child. You guessed it, it is a single linked list I am talking about. When you implement such a list you will notice that prepending is a cheap operation, whereas appending is an expensive one. Therefore balanced trees are used for the latter.

Answer (score 1):

No, because 1 is stored as a simple value on `objectFirst`, not a reference to an object, so when you do `{...objectFirst}` you're copying the value of `objectFirst.key1` to `objectNext.key1`.

However, if `objectFirst.key1` was an object instead, then the shallow copy would copy the object reference instead of creating a new object. As a result, `objectFirst.key1` and `objectNext.key2` would both reference the same object.

```
const objectFirst = {
    key1: 1,
    key2: 2,
    sharedObject: {foo: 'original string'} 
}
// we make a shallow copy with a different key2 value.
const objectSecond = {...objectFirst, key2: 4};

// changing a value in objectSecond doesn't affect objectFirst
objectSecond.key1 = 100;
console.log(objectFirst.key1); // 1

// but sharedObject is shared
objectSecond.sharedObject.foo = "new string";
console.log(objectFirst.sharedObject); // {foo: "new string"}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log(objectFirst['key1'] === objectNext['key1']); // true 

console.log(objectFirst['key2'] === objectNext['key2']); // false
```

This means `objectFirst` and `objectNext` share the `key1` property.

Comment: I don't think so, because `key1` is not reference value